# How I can use Apply or Map with If?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list of objects:

```
 list = {{1, 1, 0.05, 0.05}, {2, 2, 0.05, 0.05}, {13, 13, 0.05, 0.05}};

 list = {{x,y,Vx,Vy},{x,y,Vx,Vy},...};
```

And

```
object = {10, 10};
```

I want when I change position of object the objects from the list to follow the first object.

I try with this:

```
If[object[[1]] < #1 && #3 > 0, list = {#1,#2,-#3 ,#4}, list = {#1,#2,#3,#4}] &@@@list
If[object[[1]] > #1 && #3 < 0, list = {#1,#2,-#3 ,#4}, list = {#1,#2,#3,#4}] &@@@list
If[object[[2]] < #1 && #4 > 0, list = {#1,#2,#3 ,-#4}, list = {#1,#2,#3,#4}] &@@@list
If[object[[2]] < #1 && #4 < 0, list = {#1,#2,#3 ,-#4}, list = {#1,#2,#3,#4}] &@@@list
```

and works but only the first cycle.
I know that I can do this with:

```
If[object[[1]] < list[[1, 1]] && list[[1, 3]] > 0, list[[1, 3]] *= -1]....
```

But is very slow and not look nice :). And doesn't work completely correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
list = list /. {x_, y_, vx_, vy_} ->
          {x, y, Sign[#[[1]] - x] vx, Sign[#[[2]] - y] vy}& @ object
```

#### Edit

There is however a small subtlety: if your list is composed by exactly four sublists, the pattern `{x_, y_, vx_, vy_}` will match the whole list of lists. So, for avoiding this edge case, a good practice is to use pattern tests. I will write the four of them, but in your case one will suffice

```
list /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, vx_?NumericQ, vy_?NumericQ} ->
                          {x, y, Sign[#[[1]] - x] vx, Sign[#[[2]] - y] vy} &@ object
```

Comment: Tanks!!!I had not thought about the Sign.

Comment: I made little change because the sign of the velocity changed every cycle. I swapped Sign[#[[1]] - x] with If[(#[[1]] < x && vx > 0) || (#[[1]] > x && vx < 0), -1, 1] and works great.